# Google Charts API - “TimeOfDay” data type - Millisecond resolution

Tags: google-visualization

I made a chart with the y-axis in "timeofday" format. The data has the usual format as an array: [0,0,50,400]. The problem: Google won't recognize the milliseconds in the drawing (but in the tooltips it's shown correctly). So [0,0,50,400] (50.4 seconds) is like [0,0,50,0] (50.0 seconds) on the chart. But I need that kind of resolution. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

In chart the options object you could set the vAxis object with the field format and provide a string with the pattern you want to use here's an example:

```
new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
draw(data,
   {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
    width:600, height:400,
    vAxis: {title: "Year", format: "ss:SS"},
    hAxis: {title: "Cups"}}
```

);

Look at the vAxis object.

For the string format you should look to http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime to build you the pattern you prefer.